# Ng2-smart-table files are missing, 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, typescript, smart-table

When I try to implement ng2-smarttable in my project it gives the following error:

> http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-smart-table/build/src/ng2-smart-table/lib.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

This is also for the following files:

> localhost/:56 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-smart-table/build/src/ng2-smart-table/lib.js(…)
>   "Report this error at
>   https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues"(anonymous function) @
>   (index):56
>
> http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-smart-table/build/src/ng2-smart-table/ng2-smart-table.scss.js
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-smart-table/build/src/ng2-smart-table/ng2-smart-table.html.js
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-smart-table/build/src/ng2-smart-table/ng2-smart-table.scss.js
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-smart-table/build/src/ng2-smart-table/ng2-smart-table.html.js
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-smart-table/build/src/ng2-smart-table/components/filter/filter.scss.js
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-smart-table/build/src/ng2-smart-table/components/cell/cell.scss.js
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-smart-table/build/src/ng2-smart-table/components/pager/pager.scss.js
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:5555/node_modules/ng2-smart-table/build/src/ng2-smart-table/components/title/title.scss.js
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I installed ng2-smart-table by doing npm install --save ng2-smart-table and after that, just to make sure (and probably unnecessary) also npm install.

I did the following in my module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';

import { SmartTableComponent } from './smart-table.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        BrowserModule,
        Ng2SmartTableModule
    ],
    declarations: [SmartTableComponent],
    exports: [SmartTableComponent],
})

export class SmartTableModule { }
```

And then in the component I put the necessary standard operation as instructed by the tutorial: https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/demo. So I did:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { SensorData } from '../tables/sensor-data';
import { SensorDataService } from '../tables/sensor-data.service';

import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';

// webpack html imports

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'smart-table',
    templateUrl: 'smart-table.component.html'
})

export class SmartTableComponent {

    settings = {
        columns: {
            SendDate: {
                title: 'Send Date'
            },
            Key: {
                title: 'Key'
            },
            Value: {
                title: 'Value'
            },
            SensorId: {
                title: 'Sensor #Id'
            }
        }
    };

    source: LocalDataSource;

    public constructor(private sensorDataService: SensorDataService) {
        this.source = new LocalDataSource();

        this.sensorDataService.getSensorData(2)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.source.load(data);
                console.log(this.source);
            },
            error => console.log(<any>error));
    }

}
```

I notice it tries to get .js? I don't understand how I can fix this problem as I did everything the way it should.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My project has a `systemjs.config.js` file which maps and controls all my packages.

See below for an example:

```
var packages = {
    'angular2-highcharts': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

This `defaultExtension` could be what is holding you back.

Comment: I don't have a systemjs.config.js file. I have a feeling that it is supposed to be somehwere else but I can't seem to find it. I also have this problem with other modules like ng-bootstrap. I can't get it to load...

Comment: It wasn't in my project to start with but here is a link to set-up its fairly straight forward and manages all your packages.

Comment: Heres a good example. https://xunuo.gitbooks.io/angulajs2/content/systemjsconfigjs.html

Comment: I figured out by then that my project started with something else and I found where SystemJS config is started. The only problem I'm having is now what should I add? Because I don't have a ng2-smart-table added there unfortunately.

Comment: var packages = {
    'ng2-smart-table': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

Comment: Also "var map = { 'ng2-smart-table':  'node_modules/ng2-smart-table' };" hopefully that helps.

Comment: I added these and now it seems to work, thanks a lot. I get other errors now though like :  EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
     at eval (<anonymous>)
     at Object.eval (http://localhost:5555/app/dashboard/ng2-smart-table/ng2-smart-table.module.js:16:25)

Comment: Glad I could help. If you send me a plunker with your system config in I could possibly take a look. Could be an issue with the npm package.

Comment: I send you a file, take a look at seed.config.ts. My template I'm using is very complex as it uses a bunch of stuff of which I have no knowledge of, I rather just start from scratch and use webpack but that's not an option now. https://plnkr.co/edit/B5pajtZ0foGtXkJxDQP0?p=catalogue

Comment: rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
 'ng2-smart-table': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}  Remove the single quotes from 'ng2-smart-table' see if that fixes it.

Comment: from line 353. Don't actually think you need it there because you have it specified at line 424

Comment: Removing the '' doesn't let it parse as the "-" in ng2-smart-table breaks the code. It gives me errors. I removed that line there, but I think the above is another 'environment'. Removing the line there, doesn't help and still gives the following error: http://imgur.com/a/sHDmT. Thanks for the help so far dude, much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. If you try and add single quotes to the rxjs one above will that produce the same error?

Comment: this is becoming a very long comment chain, maybe we could use a temporary chat room for this to not clog this? I made disposable chat room, if you would like you can join: http://www.disposablechat.com/chat/danny+hoeve?password=